# list view population using only xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

I read a lot about the listView and still cant understand...
I defined the following listView with 5 column, the first is label and the rest are texboxes.
I need to add 13 rows that every textbox and labels needs to be bind to something diffrent.
So I understand that listViewItem wont do it because every object in the list, binds to somethin else..
Thank you for your help.

```
<ListView DockPanel.Dock="Top" Width="607" Height="400" Margin="10 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" BorderThickness="1">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="1" Width="120" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="2" Width="120" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="3" Width="120" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="4" Width="120" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="5" Width="120" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: so you want a static list?

Comment: Yes!! And I want to populate it in the xaml. can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly did a Grid in every item in the list like this:

```
<ListView  DataContext="{Binding CurrentMonitorCalib}"  Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="3" Height="488"  Width="444" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" BorderThickness="1">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>                 
            <GridViewColumn Header="Cal Point" Width="80"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Source" Width="90" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Failure Limit" Width="90" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Reference" Width="90" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="# DaysLimit" Width="90" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListViewItem>
        <Grid Width="441" Margin="-359,0,0,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="81" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="91" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="91" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="91" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="91" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Content="Zero" Margin="5,0" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=ZeroSource, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=ZeroFailureLimit, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Path=ZeroRef, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"  />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding Path=ZeroZNDays, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Margin="0,0,8,7" />
        </Grid>
    </ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>
                <Grid Width="442" Margin="-359,0,0,0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="81" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="91" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="91" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="91" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="91" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Content="Span" Margin="5,0"/>
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=SpanSource, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=SpanFailureLimit, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Path=SpanRef, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"  />
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding Path=SpanNDays, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"  Margin="0,0,8,7" />                    
                </Grid>
            </ListViewItem>
```

and so on.....
thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you really wane do something like this?

```
    <Grid Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,62,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="607">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width='120'/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width='120'/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width='120'/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width='120'/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width='120'/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height='30'/>
            <RowDefinition Height='30'/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- ROW 0-->
        <Label Grid.Column='0' Grid.Row='0' Content=' your lable' Height="28"/>
        <TextBox  Grid.Column='1' Grid.Row='0' Text='Text01'/>
        <TextBox  Grid.Column='2' Grid.Row='0' Text='Text02'/>
        <TextBox  Grid.Column='3' Grid.Row='0' Text='Text03'/>
        <TextBox  Grid.Column='4' Grid.Row='0' Text='Text04'/>

        <!--Row 1-->
        <Label Grid.Column='0' Grid.Row='1' Content=' your lable' Height="28"/>
        <TextBox  Grid.Column='1' Grid.Row='1' Text='Text01'/>
        <TextBox  Grid.Column='2' Grid.Row='1' Text='Text02'/>
        <TextBox  Grid.Column='3' Grid.Row='1' Text='Text03'/>
        <TextBox  Grid.Column='4' Grid.Row='1' Text='Text04'/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know I can use the grid, but I want it to look loke table and listView looks good to me. I can use "ShowGridLines=true" but it looks very bad. do you know any other way?

Comment: @user1387084 you could also use `DataGridCell` as container for your `Label` and `TextBox` so you will be able to set a style